# Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi i'm a student and i begin in dev. I try to make a histogram with chart.js. The x is the number of a week and the y a sum.  For this i make this code

```
function sumWeek(data) {
  var week = new Date(data[0].dateHisto).getWeek();
  var month = new Date(data[0].dateHisto).getMonth();
  var year = new Date(data[0].dateHisto).getFullYear();
  var table = [0, year, month, week];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(data[i].energy) / 1000;
  }

table.splice(0, 1, sum);
tableWeek.push(table);
}
for (k = 1; k <= 52; k++) {
  var resultW = dataH.filter(function(data) {
    var date = new Date(data.dateHisto);
    return date.getWeek() == k;
  });
  sumWeek(resultW);
}
```

My problem : when a week don't have data, the console write

```
index.php?page=history_currently:11606 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateHisto' of undefined
at sumWeek (index.php?page=history_currently:11606)
at createHistoWeek (index.php?page=history_currently:11640)
at index.php?page=history_currently:11414
```

Edit 09/05: My bad, i did not explain well. At a moment, a week doesn't have data and return an aray empty like 
    `[]`
When i have a data, i have 
    `{energy: "19530", dateHisto: "2019-01-28"}`
When the data is empty the function doesn't work and return the uncaught typeError. And for the moment i don't find a solution ^^ Ty for the answer

Comment: what's in `resultW`

Comment: `console.log` is your friend in javascript. A simple `if data[0]` should let you know if an object actually exists at data[0]. Then you can proceed to parse the remaining data.

Comment: It's saying data[0] is undefined. Are you sure you are passing an argument to the function?

Comment: My bad, i did not explain well. At a moment, a week doesn't have data and return an aray empty like `[]`. When i have a data, i have `{energy: "19530", dateHisto: "2019-01-28"}`. When the data is empty the function doesn't work and return the uncaught typeError. And for the moment i don't find a solution ^^ Ty for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second line of your code you take the first element out of the „data“ Array.
If the Array is empty or undefinded then there is no first element of which you can take the attribute „dateHisto“.

So you might add in the first line of the function to check if you received any input.

```
if(!data || data.length < 1){
  return
}
```

The BEST (!) way would be to check if there is any input before (!) you call the function.

Comment: Doesnt work :( My bad, i did not explain well. At a moment, a week doesn't have data and return an aray empty like `[]`. When i have a data, i have `{energy: "19530", dateHisto: "2019-01-28"}`. When the data is empty the function doesn't work and return the uncaught typeError. And for the moment i don't find a solution ^^ Ty for the answer

Comment: Yeah ikr. I replaced && by || in my answer. I mistyped. Try again pls.

Answer (score 0):

## 2 Options:

### No. 1:

The `data.dateHisto` on the following line: `var date = new Date(data.dateHisto);` is undefined

### No. 2:

The `resultW` on the following code:

```js
var resultW = dataH.filter(function(data) {
    var date = new Date(data.dateHisto);
    return date.getWeek() == k;
});
```

is an array which contains a single or more elements without `dateHisto` property, or contains it but its value is `undefined`

Comment: My bad, i did not explain well. At a moment, a week doesn't have data and return an aray empty like `[]`. When i have a data, i have `{energy: "19530", dateHisto: "2019-01-28"}`. When the data is empty the function doesn't work and return the uncaught typeError. And for the moment i don't find a solution ^^ Ty for the answer

Comment: Ok, so basically you access an entry in the array that does not exists. Add an "if" clause to check if the array is empty or not